# Looking for a simple, complete, end-to-end, example of using AJAX for a Wordpress LOOP?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, loops

Good afternoon,

I have spent a few weeks trying to find a walk through simple enough for me to successfully follow it... it seems like every one i've tried has either omitted information which the author assumed is common knowledge, or been so complicated that I failed to successfully follow it.

I need something very simple, along the lines of simply posting all the needed files (index.php, functions.php, whatever.js, etc) with detailed tagging would be enough.

... I tried following the often-referenced “[Getting Loopy](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress--wp-23232)”, without success.

I am using a localhost install of WP, which successfully runs the Ajaxify theme and the Ajax Load More plug-in, so I know the failures are all due to my own mistakes in coding :)

my goal is to use a container  to deliver the content of an independent LOOP – via AJAX - so that I can use the regular pagination feature of the primary loop elsewhere on the page. Somehow I have failed to find a simple complete example of a fully contained LOOP performed with AJAX :(

any advice is appreciated... I hope this doesn't fall under the “soliciting opinions” clause of stack